# how to download database through joomla admin panel

Tags: sql, database, joomla

I was wondering, if i were to access the `joomla` administrator panel of a website, how could i download the `sql` database? Is there such a feature?
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Normally I do the backup of the MySQL database in cPanel or Virtualmin. However you can try some of [these extensions](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/hosting-a-servers/database-management) to add this feature in the administration of Joomla.

Or this plugin, that aparently do what you want:

[**jBackup System Plugin**](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/site-security/backup/5762)

[image]